# Upgraded Linux, now CMS Made Simple is spewing errors

Tags: cms

I upgraded my host from Debian Lenny to Debian Squeeze, and now my CMS Made Simple site is spewing PHP errors all over the screen.  I thought I'd upgrade the CMS because I haven't done so in a while, but Google Chrome tells me that the CMS Made Simple site is infested with malware.

What are my options now?

Example errors:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 73

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 162

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 240

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /www/danmurn/cms/include.php:73) in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 34

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /www/danmurn/cms/include.php:73) in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 34

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/include.php on line 62

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/lib/classes/class.global.inc.php on line 184

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /www/danmurn/cms/lib/classes/class.global.inc.php on line 196
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the CMS you are running is not PHP5 compatible. Upgrading to the latest version should fix the problem, as I notice on the CMS Made Simple site they now require PHP 5.2 (which is good).

I'm not getting any malware errors from Chrome on their site, if it helps their downloads page is: http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/downloads/

As a very short term fix you could change your error_reporting value in php.ini to hide these errors, try something like:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

should work but there may be other issues, you will need to upgrade ASAP.

Comment: I get the malware errors on that page, as well as their wiki and forum pages.

Comment: Weirdly now I'm getting the warnings as well. I found this blog post (which you may not be able to view): http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/2011/02/Malware-Warning-on-cmsmadesimple-org/ which indicates that it's their ads software which was hacked, and the problem has been fixed, they're just waiting for reconsideration from Google.

Comment: Well, just to be safe I'm downloading the software with `links`.  No malware can affect you if your browser is that primitive!

Comment: And now I'm totally hosed - I tried to do the upgrade, and it tells me `Session not working, you have problem with some modules and functionality! Ask your provider, exiting!`

Comment: Do you know if that error is coming from PHP, or the CMS? If it's PHP, check /var/log/apache2/error_log for clues. Also make sure you have a backup of the CMS (database at least) if it's not already too late!

Comment: Turns out I was "upgrading" to an old version.  I grabbed the correct version (it's sometimes hard to see what you're doing in `links`) and it upgraded fine.